# Replace a character and add 'greater than sign' in each line

Tags: python, replace, line, addition, readline

**Input:**

```
Aa Ab,Ac,Ad
Ba Bb,Bc,Bd
Ca Cb,Cc,Cd
```

**Expected output:**

```
>Aa,Ab,Ac,Ad
>Ba,Bb,Bc,Bd
>Ca,Cb,Cc,Cd
```

**Output:**

```
>A
>a
>,
>A
>b
 :
>C
>d
```

**Code:**

```
with open(input, 'r') as fr, open(add_greater_than_sign, 'a') as fa:

    while True:
        line = fr.readline()
        line_replaced = line.replace('\t',',')
    
        appendText='>'
        for name in line_replaced:
            fa.write(appendText + name.rstrip() + '\n')
    
        if not line:
            break
```

I tried to replace a character and add 'greater than sign' in each line with this code. However, the result was like 'Output' file. Could you let me know what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `for name in line_replaced:` you loop over each character of a line and write one line per character.

Keep it simple:

```
with open(input, 'r') as fr, open(add_greater_than_sign, 'a') as fa:
    for line in fr:
        fa.write('>'+line.replace('\t', ','))
```

*NB. avoid using `input` as variable name, this is a python builtin*